# Adaptive air suspension problems

Tags: suspension, audi

Adaptive air suspension on 2005 Audi A8 is slam to the ground only in the front what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

The first thing I'd do is attach VAG-COM or VCDS to the vehicle and get the fault codes.

There are two possible reasons for the problem.  It could be that there is a physical fault or it could be something as simple as an electrical fault with the control circuits.  This is why my first port of call would be to check the fault codes instead of going right ahead with stripping the cars suspension.